# Refresh indicator with AnimatedList

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animatedlist

I am successfully able to call the API function during pull to refresh action.
I also understand the `insertitem` and `removeitem` function on `AnimatedList` using `global key`
but I am having a hard time looking for references wherein the refresh indicator and animated list are **combined**.

If you could share a clue on what to use for the `AnimatedList` so that it gets updated or **rebuild** the list, that would be enough for me to handle the rest.